# Play Framework appending #_=_ to redirect after Facebook auth via OAuth2?

Tags: java, facebook, playframework, oauth-2.0

I'm doing a simple redirect after calling OAuth2::retrieveAccessToken() with Play Framework. I'm having funny characters appended to the URL that I never put there, so the end result looks as follows:

> http://localhost:9000/#_=_

Where on earth does the #_=_ come from? Here's my route definition from the routes file:

> GET   /    Application.index

Here's the code snippet of the controller dealing with the Facebook authentication:

```
public static void facebookConnect() {
    OAuth2 facebook = new OAuth2(
        "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize",
        "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token",
        "2#############6",
        "c##############################2"
    );

    if(OAuth2.isCodeResponse()) {
        OAuth2.Response oauthResponse = facebook.retrieveAccessToken(facebookAuthUrl());
        if(oauthResponse.error == null) {
            //... Somewhere here, something is causing #_=_ to be appended to the URL?
            Application.index();
        }
    }
    facebook.retrieveVerificationCode(facebookAuthUrl());
}
```

EDIT:

According to [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/), Facebook changed their API recently to include the *=* if request_uri is empty, the problem is...my request_uri has been explicitly set?

Comment: Just tried running the facebook-oauth2 sample that comes with the Play Framework download, and it does exactly the same, appending #_=_ after redirecting.

Comment: I've created a bug about this issue: http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=20504

Comment: I have the same issue. I get the characters even if I fill in the redirect_uri. cheers!

Comment: Add the following to your head tag to resolve this issue: `<script type="text/javascript">if (window.location.hash == '#_=_')window.location.hash = '';</script>`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This was added after a security update.

From the [Facebook developer blog](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/):

> **Change in Session Redirect Behavior**
>
> This week, we started adding a fragment `#_=_` to the redirect_uri
>   when this field is left blank. Please ensure that your app can handle
>   this behavior.

Comment: Description of the security vulnerability they solved with this: https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/08/lessons-from-facebooks-security-bug-bounty-program/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these characters come from the facebook callback. I was getting a FB callback like

```
localhost:9000?someparams#code=verylongcodefromfacebook
```

I could get rid of the # just by sanitizing the params before requesting the access token.

Comment: The only param set is "code" which is needed for retrieveAccessToken, if I touch this, retrieveAccessToken will fail.