# Weird url appended "#_=_"

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Play Framework appending #*=* to redirect after Facebook auth via OAuth2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324944/play-framework-appending-to-redirect-after-facebook-auth-via-oauth2)

Has anyone else seen this happen?

I am building a Facebook canvas app using the Facebook PHP SDK, and some Javascript.
Now when I take the user through the OAuth authentication flow, I have noticed that the URL in the  browser automatically gets appended with this `"#_=_"` , so my URL starts looking like this:

```
http://apps.facebook.com/xxxxxxxxxxxx/#_=_
```

and when I redirect to the app profile page the URL is this:

```
http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=xxxxxxxxxxxx#_=_
```

I am redirecting using

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href='$appcanvasurl';</script>"
```

to the canvas URL, and

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>top.location.href='$appprofurl';</script>"
```

for app profile page.

So why is this `#_=_` getting appended?

**Update:**

According to [this bug on the tracker](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/318390728250352?browse=search_507eb75370b6e0154879360), this is by design, and giving a value for the `redirect_uri` does not change this.

And according to the [official facebook reply on that page](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/318390728250352?fb_comment_id=fbc_10151751027806988_358309612_10151883481651988) (have to be logged in to Facebook to view the post):

> > This has been marked as 'by design' because it prevents a potential security vulnerability.
> >
> > Some browsers will append the hash fragment from a URL to the end of a new URL to which they have been redirected (if that new URL does not itself have a hash fragment).
> >
> > For example if example1.com returns a redirect to example2.com, then a browser going to example1.com#abc will go to example2.com#abc, and the hash fragment content from example1.com would be accessible to a script on example2.com.
> >
> > Since it is possible to have one auth flow redirect to another, it would be possible to have sensitive auth data from one app accessible to another.
> >
> > This is mitigated by appending a new hash fragment to the redirect URL to prevent this browser behavior.
> >
> > If the aesthetics, or client-side behavior, of the resulting URL are of concern, it would be possible to use window.location.hash (or even a server-side redirect of your own) to remove the offending characters.

Comment: i have noticed that the #_=_ is still getting appended even when `redirect_uri` has been specified. There is a workaround though, using javascript at this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/7131909/720508 and here : http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7338853/php-location-header-ignore-hash/7340855#7340855

Comment: Add the following to your head tag to resolve this issue: `<script type="text/javascript">if (window.location.hash == '#_=_')window.location.hash = '';</script>`

Comment: @SafranAli that doesn't solve it, please excuse me for this late follow up. window.location.hash is anyway empty, only parent or top location has this hash i guess. window here refers to the iframe that the app is running in, the hash of the parent frame is #_=_ i think. share your thoughts please.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

See This:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/552/

> #### Change in Session Redirect Behavior
>
> This week, we started adding a fragment `#_=_` to the redirect_uri
>   when this field is left blank. Please ensure that your app can handle
>   this behavior.

Comment: awesome, thanks, have to keep reading the blog, and not just code :)

Comment: When what field is left blank? I am getting this and nothing else. What is the answer?

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea were you able to find the answer to the blank field causing this problem?

Comment: @EdmundRojas The only way I could avoid this bug was to send the type as 'token' instead of 'code' (even though the documentation says it can be one or the other) and then I get a token in the fragment. This is annoying as a code would have been in a parameter. But at least I have a token to do something with rather than nothing.