# Hybridauth with facebook adds #_=_ to the url

Tags: facebook, hybridauth, hybridauthprovider

a. Why does Hybridauth login with facebook add #*=* to the url after a successful login?

and

b. Can it be removed?

Comment: Not yet, please post here if you do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Hybridauth issue, its a 'by design' implementation in the Facebook OAuth flow. Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7485111/weird-url-appended) for more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion is to remove character from string
for example

```
public function login($provider) {

  $provider = str_replace("#_=_", "", $provider);
```

Try that.