# Facebook authentication appends #_=_ to redirect url using Nancy.SimpleAuthentication

Tags: facebook-oauth, nancy

I am using Nancy.SimpleAuthentication and Nancy.Authentication.Forms for Facebook authentication.

After authenticating with Facebook and redirecting back to my site it appends #*=* to the url.
I read that Facebook append this when the redirect_uri is not filled out.

However when I trace the requests, I can see the redirect_uri is being set.

How do I fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Play Framework appending #\_=\_ to redirect after Facebook auth via OAuth2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324944/play-framework-appending-to-redirect-after-facebook-auth-via-oauth2)

Comment: Same issue but different framework. From the logs it looks like redirect_uri is set, which should solve this but it does not, hence the question.

Comment: Do you have some social auth library for sharing like AddThis?

Comment: No AddThis or similar, it is a very basic html page.

Answer (score 0):

You can't 'fix' this- it's appended deliberately by Facebook as a security measure, as outlined in the duplicate question.

What do you need to fix?  An anchor reference in the redirect uri is unlikely to cause any problems...