# Check on Facebook #_=_ snipped in URL

Tags: asp.net, facebook, url, request

I'm using Facebook authentication on my site. On redirect Facebook appends this to my URL `#_=_`, e.g. `http://www.example.com/account#_=_`
Also see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324944/play-framework-appending-to-redirect-after-facebook-auth-via-oauth2).

I want to check in my codebehind whether the `#_=_` snippet exists, but none of the methods I tried return the right string to run that check on.

All on the `Request` object I tried:

- Rawurl
- URL
- PathAndQuery
- OriginalString
- AbsoluteUri
- AbsolutePath
- Query
- Fragment
- QueryString

How can I get the right string?

Comment: You can only read it from Javascript. The browser will not send it to your server

Comment: Thank you...that should be the answer :)

Comment: I wouldn't rely on that anchor fragment being there.  Not sure what you're trying to do with it...